# Why did I get an error about null pointer while customizing a comparator

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, comparator

I'm trying to solve this problem on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals

> Given a collection of intervals, merge all overlapping intervals.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: intervals = [[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
> Output: [[1,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
> Explanation: Since intervals [1,3] and [2,6] overlaps, merge them into [1,6].
> ```
>
> Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: intervals = [[1,4],[4,5]]
> Output: [[1,5]]
> Explanation: Intervals [1,4] and [4,5] are considered overlapping.
> ```
>
> NOTE: input types have been changed on April 15, 2019. Please reset to default code definition to get new method signature.
>
> Constraints:
>
> ```
> intervals[i][0] <= intervals[i][1]
> ```

I simply got a simple idea: sort the input and do the merge.

Here is my code:

```
vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>> &intervals)
{
    vector<vector<int>> res;
    if (intervals.empty()) {
        return res;
    }
    std::sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), [](const vector<int> e1, const vector<int> e2) {
        if (e1[0] == e2[0]) {
            return e1[1] <= e2[1];     // ERROR!!!
        }
        return e1[0] < e2[0];
    });
    res.push_back(intervals[0]);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < intervals.size(); i++) {
        if (res.back()[1] >= intervals[i][0]) {
            if (res.back()[1] <= intervals[i][1]) {
                res.back()[1] = intervals[i][1];
            }
        } else {
            res.push_back(intervals[i]);
        }

    }
    return res;
}
```

In fact the error comes from the line of `std::sort`.

When I execute the code on Leetcode, I get an error:

```
Line 1052: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int>, int>::value_type' (aka 'const int') (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1061:9
```

But If I change the comparator as below:

```
std::sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), [](const vector<int> e1, const vector<int> e2) {
    if (e1[0] == e2[0]) {
        return e1[1] < e2[1];    // change <= into <
    }
    return e1[0] < e2[0];
});
```

It will work as expected without any error.

I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your comparator, this comparison:

```
return e1[1] <= e2[1];
```

does not satisfy a *strict-weak-ordering* on the elements being compared. e.g. if

```
e1: {1, 2}
e2: {1, 2}
```

then comparing `e1`, and `e2` will return `true`, regardless of the comparison order.

Violating this requirement of `std::sort` invokes undefined behavior. In this case, the UB-sanitizer has helpfully diagnosed the issue for you.

On the other hand, this comparison:

```
return e1[1] < e2[1];
```

is perfectly fine, since it establishes a *strict-weak-ordering* as needed.

Answer (score 0):

- Looks pretty good! Almost there!
- We would do a regular `std::sort()` then use `std::min()` and `std::max()`, don't really have to use a comparator:

```
// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto improve_runtime = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();



struct Solution {
    static const std::vector<std::vector<int>> merge(
            std::vector<std::vector<int>>& intervals
    ) {
        std::sort(std::begin(intervals), std::end(intervals));
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> merged;

        if (std::size(intervals) >= 1) {
            merged.emplace_back(intervals[0]);
        }

        for (std::size_t index = 0; index < std::size(intervals); ++index) {
            const std::vector<int> interval = intervals[index];
            const std::vector<int> tail = merged.back();

            if (tail[1] >= interval[0]) {
                merged.pop_back();
                merged.emplace_back(std::vector<int> {
                    std::min(tail[0], interval[0]),
                    std::max(interval[1], tail[1])
                });

            } else {
                merged.emplace_back(interval);
            }
        }

        return merged;
    }

};


// int main() {
//     std::vector<std::vector<int>> intervals = {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {8, 10}, {15, 18}};
//     std::vector<std::vector<int>> merged = Solution().merge(intervals);

//     for (auto& interval : merged) {
//         std::cout << "[" << interval[0] << "\t" << interval[1] << "]\n";
//     }
// }
```

PS:

- LeetCode runs on C++17.
- Also make sure to consistently use the `std::`, except for the contests.

---

- Here is your working algorithm, without using the comparator:

```
// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto improve_runtime = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();


struct Solution {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> merge(
                                   std::vector<std::vector<int>>& intervals
    ) {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> res;

        if (intervals.empty()) {
            return res;
        }

        std::sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end());

        res.push_back(intervals[0]);

        for (std::size_t i = 1; i < intervals.size(); i++) {
            if (res.back()[1] >= intervals[i][0]) {
                if (res.back()[1] <= intervals[i][1]) {
                    res.back()[1] = intervals[i][1];
                }

            } else {
                res.push_back(intervals[i]);
            }

        }

        return res;
    }

};


int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> intervals = {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {8, 10}, {15, 18}};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> merged = Solution().merge(intervals);

    for (auto& interval : merged) {
        std::cout << "[" << interval[0] << "\t" << interval[1] << "]\n";
    }
}
```

#### Edited based on [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker)'s advice:

> Names that contain two consecutive underscores (**optimize**) and
> names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are
> reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Great. Nice one~~

Comment: Names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__optimize__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.